# Handling Login Form Validation

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how I should use the login form submission to validate the user login credentials. With this template I have it includes a javascript validation code however I do have my own validation code on the server side I want to use (php). After it goes through the php validation I want it to redirect to either the login form again if there was a problem validating the login OR redirect to the dashboard if there was a successful login.

JS validation:

```
$(window).load(function(){
/*
 * Validate the form when it is submitted
 */
var validatelogin = $("form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
              ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted.'
              : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted.';
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
            $('.box .content').alertBox(message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
            $('.box .content .alert').css({
                width: '',
                margin: '0',
                borderLeft: 'none',
                borderRight: 'none',
                borderRadius: 0
            });
        } else {
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
        }
    },
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            var self = this;
            $.each(errorList, function() {
                var $input = $(this.element);
                var $label = $input.parent().find('label.error').hide();
                $label.addClass('red');
                $label.css('width', '');
                $input.trigger('labeled');
                $label.fadeIn();
            });
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        window.location.replace('dashboard.html');
    }
});
});
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usermanagement extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}   

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $bodyContent = "login";//which view file
    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "cpanel/index";//which view file
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $user_id = $this->loggedin->check_login($username, $password);

        if(! $user_id)
        {
           redirect('/'); 
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
                'user_id' => $user_id
            ));
            redirect('cpanel/index');
        }
    }
}

function logout()
{
   $this->session->sess_destroy();
   $this->index();
}       

}

/* End of file usermanagement.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/usermanagement.php */
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What should I be doing? Should I have it be going to my dashboard via js or php.

Comment: It's nice to validate on the client side because you can provide feedback quicker, but it's **mandatory** to validate on the server side.  So, you can either do just the server side validation, or you can do both. Make sure the two sets of rules are in agreement of course.

Comment: So I can do without the submit handler for the js code?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to do something fancy, like showing an "ok/not-ok" indicator while the user is typing.  But for a login form that seems kind-of unnecessary to me personally.  It's useful for things where the validity rules might not be obvious, like when a new user is *creating* a password.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is to how to detect the validation of logged user if I understood correctly. In the CodeIgniter controller function you can just examine it and `echo` it with a code to understand it in client-side(JavaScript). For example return something like this:

```
if(valid){
  echo "1, You're logged in successfully"; 
}
```

Then you can split it in the JS and use the code and message part.

For navigation with JS use:

`window.location.href = 'yourlocation';`

If your question is related to how to get the CI function and use it in jQuery ajax, I can tell you that you can use it just like the old times. `url: 'yourrootfolder/yourcontroller/yourfunction'`

Hope this help.